# Need help formatting numbers C++

Tags: c++, math, numbers

Can someone help a rookie? If i have a number `4.561` that is derived from an equation, how can i ONLY display the `.561` and ignore the `4`?

Thanks in advance. I am new to programming and this is part of an assignment. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm coding in `c++`.

Comment: Help us help you.  What language are you using?

Comment: Sorry. I automatically assumed. It's C++.

Comment: There must be a nice formatting way, but in a pinch if n=4.561 you could display n-trunc(n)

Comment: this is not related to formatting number whatsoever

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you need but do check this out.

```
float f = 4.561;
f = f-(long)f;
cout << "Value of f is : " << f << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would feel much better with using `floor` from `math.h`:

```
f = 4.561
if (f>=0) f=f-floor(f);
 else     f=f-ceil(f);
// here f = 0.561
```

for these reasons:

1. As you do not have control over casting to integral type (`f-long(f)`) at least I do not know if it is clearly defined as a standard it is using integer part or rounding. Not to mention custom types implementation.
2. what if your floating value holds bigger number then your integral type can hold? I know there are not that many mantissa bits for fractional part for bigger numbers but you did not specify which floating data-type you are using if 32/64/80/128/256 bits or more so hard to say and if the integer part is bigger then your integral data-type used to cut off the non fractional part then you would be in trouble with `f-long(f)`.

**PS.**

The if statement could be avoided with masking in and out the sign bit before and after the operation. For example on standard 32bit float it looks like this:

```
float f=4.561;         // input value
DWORD *dw=(DWORD*)(&f); // pointer to f as integer type to access bits
DWORD m;               // sign storage
m=(*dw)&0x80000000;    // store sign bit to m
(*dw)&= 0x7FFFFFFF;    // f=fabs(f)
f-=floor(f);
(*dw)|=m;              // restore original sign from m
// here f = 0.561
```

If you do not have `DWORD` use any unsigned 32 bit integer instead